# Use regex to find shortest possible match from multiline string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a multi-line **string** with given representation:

```
text1 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n
<hr>\n
Bitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\n
text2 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n
text3 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n
<hr>\n
Bitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\n
text2 (arbitrary chars lines)\n
\n
```

I want to match this **substring** that always occures twice in the string (once always in the end):

```
<hr>\n
Bitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\n
text2 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n
```

When I try to match with `re.search`, it returns the long match:

```
regex = re.compile('<hr>\n'
                   'Bitmap: [\S\n ]*'
                   '$')
print(re.search(regex, string).group())

>> '<hr>\nBitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\ntext2 (arbitrary chars and lines)\ntext3 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n<hr>\nBitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\ntext2 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n\n'
```

Is it possible to use `regex` to find the short match?

**Solution**:
Lookahead with OR operator returns two matches (one longer and one shorter):

```
regex = re.compile('<hr>\n'
                   'Bitmap: [\S]*\n'
                   '[\s\S]*?(?=<hr>|\n\Z)')
print(re.findall(regex, string))
>> ['<hr>\nBitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\ntext2 (arbitrary chars and lines)\ntext3 (arbitrary chars and lines)\n', '<hr>\nBitmap: ./media/logo.bmp\ntext2 (arbitrary chars lines)\n']
```

Comment: How many matches do you want to get in total? And what do you mean exactly by the shortest match?

Comment: Note regexps by themselves do not match shortest or longest substrings. With `re.findall(regex, string)`, you get all occurrences, and once you have them, you may further fllter the matches, by length, etc. You may also access the last match by using the `[-1]` index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(?m)^<hr>\r?\nBitmap:[\s\S]*?(?=^<hr>$|\Z)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/i64K0W/4).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <hr>                     '<hr>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Bitmap:                  'Bitmap:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all but \n,
                           \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <hr>                     '<hr>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                             "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I wonder if negative lookahead `(?!<hr>)` can be used to exclude the first match and return just the second match

Comment: @user46581 I do not know what you mean by that: lookaheads only help determine if a match is valid at a specific location. `(?!<hr>)`  means do not match at the current location if it is followed with `<hr>`

Answer (score 0):

This works: `<hr>\nBitmap:.*\n(?:.*\n){1,2}`

See: https://regex101.com/r/i64K0W/3

The problem in your regex was the `*`, which is greedy.

Comment: Your regex does not match the first match in full, it has three lines.

Comment: Updated it. Since in your "I want to match this substring" example you only listed one line after the "Bitmap" I only matched for one.

Comment: text2 can have arbitrary number of lines (the OP was updated) so this is not generally working. Better approach would be to use end of string operator since the substring always occurs in the end of string

Comment: You are right, the solution might be using lookahead/lookbehind..